# Strange behaviour from PHP. var_dump(390.0) outputs 38:

Tags: php

Test file:

```
<?php
$var        = 0.28682926829268;
$roundedVar = round($var, 2);

var_dump($roundedVar);
var_dump(is_float($roundedVar));
echo "Rounded var: $roundedVar";
?>
```

Output:

```
float(0.28:)
bool(true)
Rounded var: 0.28:
```

Note the strange colon character that appears after 0.28 both in the var_dump and in the echo output.

After discovering that, I figured PHP must be corrupted somehow.  So I uninstalled and reinstalled PHP.  I reinstalled the same version of PHP, as detailed below.  I re-ran the test code and got the same result

I then reinstalled both PHP and Apache 2.2.  After doing that the test case above worked as expected, but then another error turned up, that I reduced to the following test case.

Test file:

```
<?php
$var = 390;
echo "var: "        ; var_dump($var           );
echo "is_float(): " ; var_dump(is_float($var) );
echo "is_string(): "; var_dump(is_string($var));
echo "echo: $var<br/>\n";

$var = 390.0;
echo "var: "        ; var_dump($var           );
echo "is_float(): " ; var_dump(is_float($var) );
echo "is_string(): "; var_dump(is_string($var));
echo "echo: $var<br/>\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
var: int(390) is_float(): bool(false) is_string(): bool(false) echo: 390
var: float(38:) is_float(): bool(true) is_string(): bool(false) echo: 38:
```

Can anyone explain this strange behavior?

---

Updates:

I found by running hardware diagnostics that the the CPU on the server was overheating.  When that problem was fixed so that the hardware diagnostic passed, the error stopped appearing in the logs  (see the accepted answer below).

For anyone else investigating a similar problem, I found discussion of another weird PHP bug involving floating-point numbers and colon suffixes at the following URL.  Not sure whether related.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51396

---

PHP version info:

[image]

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the php code, i just ran it and it didn't printed any extra colon. Can you post your SQL query

Comment: I'm not able to re-produce your issue. https://3v4l.org/iuSqs

Comment: The problem with the SQL query was fully explained by the strange output of the round() function.  What PHP versions did you test?

Comment: I have now tested the code on another server that has according to the phpinfo() output, and identical version of PHP installed.  I could not reproduce the strange behavior.  So I will try reinstalling PHP.

Comment: Here is a link, explaining 6 years ago, that php 5.2 is OUTDATED ,  at least upgrade to 5.4 - We are right now at 7.2.5 public stable... come on http://bigemployee.com/stop-using-php-5-2/

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  That is an option for me, but it will involve some work to update the code.  I'm wondering though if a hardware fault could explain this.  If that was the case, then upgrading would be a waste of time.

Comment: It can't be a hardware issue, or you would get a lot of side effects. By upgrading you will also gain a lot of speed and gain a lot of memory, with the same code. I have done a lot of migration, and there is nothing bad from 5.4 to 7.2. There is just more features, but 99% fully retro compatible. Maybe if you are using --magic quotes-- http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: I expect that there will just be a few deprecated function calls to replace for the codebase to work with a later version of PHP.  It's a pretty large codebase though so that will take a while.

Comment: My plan now is to run some hardware diagnostics on the server, and if all pass, then upgrade PHP and Apache.  Thanks again.

Comment: Update: I ran a processor diagnostic tool from Intel, and found a fault!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CPU was faulty.

I downloaded an Intel CPU diagnostic tool from here:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792/Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool

Relevant output:

```
Current Junction Temperature is 99C
Current Degrees Below Max       1C
Maximum Junction Temp Allowed  100C
Test Result - FAIL
Please check your Processor Thermal Solution
```